Transformer Cores Datasheets - Core Loss Information
Transformer core datasheets generally have Core loss - Pv (kW/m3) versus Flux Density - B (mT) graph but some doesn't, instead it is given in a table as shown in the picture below for one of the EE core type (page 19).
The unit is generally kW/m3 or mW/cm3. For example for PL-5 material core loss is given as 0.03.
Unit is watt and measuring condition is given as 100 kHz, 200 mT and 100 degree.

Is this 0.03 W based on m3, cm3 or what?

0.03 W seems too low for the given measuring conditions, isn't it?


PL-5 material has Pv (kW/m3) -B (mT) graph in the beginning of the datasheet separately (page 6). Here the loss is at around 100 mW/cm3, not even matching with what is given in the table which is 0.03.
I am confused about these 2 questions.

Source: https://github.com/alpelectronix/Alp-Yesilyurt/blob/main/15W%20Flyback%20Converter%20Notlar/Datasheet/N%C3%BCve/Samwha%20Full.pdf

Source: https://github.com/alpelectronix/Alp-Yesilyurt/blob/main/15W%20Flyback%20Converter%20Notlar/Datasheet/N%C3%BCve/Samwha%20Full.pdf

Source: https://github.com/alpelectronix/Alp-Yesilyurt/blob/main/15W%20Flyback%20Converter%20Notlar/Datasheet/N%C3%BCve/Samwha%20Full.pdf

What's the volume of the specific core?

Ve=33 mm3 @Andyaka

I find it hard to believe that the effective volume is equivalent to a cube of side dimensions 3.2 mm. Please link the core data sheet and be specific about the part name for the core.

The screenshot of the core set parameter is added in the question (See Picture 3 ). The link is already provided below the picture (Page 19)  @Andyaka

PL-5 is the core material. This applies to many many cores. I'm asking about the specific core type and its specific data sheet. I suspect it's now a toroid but, you need to state that and link that toroid type.

EE core,  EE0505S , page 19 @Andyaka

The table is referring to specific cores. That is a core with a given material, shape and size. The core loss is in units W for this specific core. Core loss density in the second graph is a material property that can be considered independent from core shape and size.
So what you are missing is the core volume of the specific core. With that you should be able to calculate core loss from core loss density or vice versa.

core volume (Ve) = 33mm3 . 0.03 W / 33mm3 = 909 kW/m3 I believe something is wrong in my calculation

Reading the core loss density from the graph should result in 500 kW/m³ so there is indeed a difference and the calculation looks ok. So what could be the reasons for this?
The core loss density from the material data graph is based on typical data acquired with a toroidal core. Toroids have a very uniform flux density distribution which leads to lower core losses than with other core shapes. It is also typical data while the core loss data from the table appears to be a maximum value.
The data from the table also looks like a rounded value. E.g. just look at the slightly larger core in the column to the right. It has a volume of 40 mm³ instead of 33mm³ but still has the same core loss of 0.03W.

Thank you sir, core volume (Ve) = 33mm3 . 0.03 W / 33mm3 = 909 kW/m3  I believe something is wrong in my calculation, what do you thing sir ? @Lars Hankeln

@Mhan Just added some more lines trying to explain that.
